# Release Android APK size is double than debug APK

Tags: android

When I install the app by using the "play" button on Android studio, the APK size is only 1119 KB. But when I generate a signed APK the size becomes 2688 KB.

I am using

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

But still the release APK size is doubling up from the debug version.

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html

Comment: How are you creating your packages for the debug apk? If you use the "play" button in Android Studio to create your debug builds, it might be the case that you are getting a 'split' build to speed up builds. Are you using Native libraries?

Comment: @saberrider you are correct. I was using the instant run option in Android studio. That generates a small size APK. If we turn of that option then Debug APK size becomes almost twice the size of the release APK.